# Comparing two JPEG IMAGES and displaying differences

Tags: pattern-matching, imaging

Images are of the same object taken at different time intervals.
Software solutions - to be implemented in hardware.
High rate of performance most important in hardware implementation

Comment: Could you word this in the form of a question, and include more detail?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say the question is "code this up for me".

Comment: Is this a question? What are the issues/questions you have now?

Comment: LOL . Its a bunch of statements. 

He forgot to put sudo at the start

Comment: This could be done by hardcoding which includes searching each pixels color it contains and their distance to start point (start point: considering x0, y0 in this case) and comparing with other pictures pixel color at the same distace to the start point. 

There can be different sized pictures for that reason i would consider giving their distance to start point as percentages.(just another idea for different sized picture comparing)

Change topic with the coding language that you wanna merge this idea with or simply go buy a product that does this...

Easy as that.. lol

Answer (score 3):

I believe Perceptual Diff does what you want...

http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Despite the fact the question seems to be after hardware and some kind of technique rather than a tool, for the sake of posterity it's worth mentioning that you can do this with Beyond Compare plugins.

Not free but worth the money in my humble opinion: http://www.scootersoftware.com